# Make a QT form not show up in taskbar

Tags: c++, qt

Any suggestions on how I can make a QT form not appear in the taskbar ?
Currently when I show a QT form it appears on the taskbar as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you use QDialog as a base class it will share it's parent taskbar entry (don't forget to set the parent), also setting [Qt::Dialog](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qt.html#WindowType-enum) as [window flag](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) should do the trick for a QWidget.

If you can't get it to work prepare a little sample code that we can compile and run and tell us more about Qt version, os version, compiler and rest of your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will definitely give this a try